# Wrong characters after deploying android build with Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, character

I have been googling for some time and I can't seem to find an answer to this. When I simulate the app the special characters (such as á,à,â,ř...) are displayed correctly. But the moment I build it and install it on my Android device they are displayed like:

- "devä›t" in stead of "devět"
- "barÃ¡k" in stead of "barák"

Any idea of why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future people wondering, the solution was adding this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

To the head of the html document.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add charset="UTF-8" in your meta tag of your html page which will display the special characters as they are represented.